# Pipenv script won't run on Windows using Git Bash

Tags: python, git-bash, pipenv

I am running Gitbash for windows and have installed pipenv using pip. Yet when I invoke `pipenv` nothing happens:

[image]

Since there isn't a `command not found` error, I believe the script is recognized it just isn't running properly.

Pipenv is installed globally:

[image]

I also can confirm that the Scripts folder is in the file path:

[image]

I don't think it is a problem with Gitbash because I can run other pip packages in the same scripts folder:

[image]

I'm also able to run `python pipenv.exe` but not `pipenv.exe` when in the Scripts folder:

[image]

Comment: If executing the file that is in `/c/users/.../Scripts` works, but calling directly `pipenv.exe` not, maybe it's because the latter is not the same as the former. Maybe this is due to the fact that there is an other `pipenv` in your `PATH`?

Comment: @BlackBeans That's would make sense. Do you know of an easy way to determine the location of a script?

Comment: If you were using Bash, I would suggest `which` or `whereis`, but since I don't know exactly what git-bash is I don't really know..

Comment: @BlackBeans After running `type -a pipenv` it returned only one location which is the Scripts folder, so I don't believe this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled with this myself untill just now.
I've got a few suggestions.

**SOLUTION 1:**
I was calling Poetry to try and make sense of it as well and then I tried calling both applications from Powershell. Both work as inteded.

**SOLUTION 2:**
Calling `python -m pipenv`, as sugested in this [other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345529/pipenv-install-pipenv-shell-not-working-with-git-bash-on-windows-10), also works as intended. You could alias the command to `pipenv` in git bash and call it a day too.
Quoting the docs on the `-m` flag:

> When called with `-m module-name`, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.

Quoting [appdividend.com](https://appdividend.com/2021/02/18/what-is-the-meaning-of-python-m-flag/):

> The `-m` flag in Python searches the `sys.path` for the named module and executes its contents as the `__main__` module.

It goes through whatever path is in `which pipenv` and executes the module as a script.

**SOLUTION 3:**
This is how I ended up fixing my Pipenv blunder.
Reinstall Python and all packages to `AppData`.
MINGW64 was having trouble seeing Pipenv in `C:\Program Files`. I also noticed that I had some packages in `AppData\Roaming` as well, so I figured I'd reinstall Python, unticking the `Install for all users` option (to trigger `AppData` installation) to see if I could wrangle all packages together.
After that I tried installing Pipenv and succeeded in calling it as expected.

This is all highly anecdotal. I have no idea why MINGW64 failed to call JUST Pipenv and not Poetry, but this is how I've fixed it on my end.

Comment: I realized I never gave this answer the upvote and acceptance it deserves. In the end, I managed to get it working with your third solution.