# pipenv install/pipenv shell not working with Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, bash, pipenv

I am having a hard time getting the pipenv install and pipenv shell commands to work when using Git Bash for Windows 10. When using powershell, I am able to successfully create a new virtual environment and use pipenv shell to enter the environment, but when using bash, nothing happens and it just proceeds to go to a flashing prompt.

Bash recognizes other commands like pip list, but pipenv doesn't seem to be working for me. I am very new to all of this so I may be missing something obvious, but I have searched for this issue to the best of my ability and even went through the pipenv documentation.

My software versions are:

- Windows 10 Home 21H1
- git version 2.35.1
- bash version 4.4.23
- Python 3.10.2

Update: So I feel like an idiot, but am still left with a question. I have been fooling with this since yesterday and after posting, I remembered when I had installed a virtual environment using venv using the command 'python -m venv', so I tried running 'python -m pipenv install' and it worked. I also have to use 'python -m pipenv shell' to launch the shell.

Why do I have to do this? Every tutorial I've watched on setting up my environment and installing pipenv has just used pipenv install/shell.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue and I doubt it's an issue in `pipenv`.

I resolve this by uninstalling the latest version `2022.1.8` of `pipenv` and install the version of `2021.5.29`, which is a working version on my another PC.

In case you don't know how to do this:

```
pip uninstall pipenv
pip install pipenv==2021.5.29
```

Update: after downgrade to `2021.5.29`, and then upgrade to the latest version, it still works. Now I have no idea what is the root cause.

Comment: Interesting. I’ll look into that. Thanks for the info.